# How to send request and proceed response, and send back to Client?

Tags: java, servlets, request, response

A Client calls the Servlet via a HTTP Request (via the Browser, post), then the Servlet should send a request (get) to a external Website, and receive the response (post) from the Website.
The Servlets proceed the response and sends a response (post) to the Client.

My question is how to send and receive a request/response inside a Servlet and send something back to the Client?

Comment: You mean Webservices ??

Comment: with external webside i mean a normal webservice like ebay, which gives back a post response in html f.E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create the URL and then use URLConnection object to connect and receive the response as below for GET request/response

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  //connecting to url
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));  //stream to resource
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)   //reading data
   responsestring += str+"\n";//process the response and save it in some string or so
in.close();  //closing stream
response.getWriter().write(responsestring);
```

**UPDATE**
For POST request/response do this

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");

String urlParameters = ..;

con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    res.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
//process response
response.getWriter().write(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set **attributes** of the request in this form: `request.setAttribute(String key, Object value)`.

Example:

```
public class FindPerson extends HttpServlet {

    // ... doGet implementation

    @Override
    protected void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // data to send to the client
        String name = "John White";
        int age = 54;



        // Adding attributes to the request
        request.setAttribute( "personName", name );
        request.setAttribute( "personAge", age );

        // Sending the result to the.jsp page
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/result.jsp" ).forward( request, response );

        }
    }
}
```

After this, you can read this data on the JSP page using JSTL:

```
<p>Name: ${ requestScope.personName } </p>
<p>Age: ${ requestScope.personAge } </p>
```

where `personName` and `personAge` are **keys** of the map. You set them using `request.setAttribute`.

!!!UPDATED!!!

In your case, you will call other servlets, which will perform requests to the external site, etc. All this (gathering of data from external site + processing this data) is to be put instead of the code which is setting values of name and age (see example above).
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  //connecting to url
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));  //stream to resource
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)   //reading data
    responsestring += str+"\n";//process the response and save it in some string or so
in.close();  //closing stream
response.getWriter().write(responsestring);
```